# How to convert element int in list that inside the tuple in python

Tags: python

How to convert element int in list that inside the tuple in python,

so what i want is convert this z

```
z = ([(468000,)], [(309000,)], [(1216000,)])
```

to a single int value in python

```
za = 468000  
zb = 309000
```

Comment: Will your inner list always contain just one tuple?

Comment: Use indexing? Please show your attempts and explain why they failed.

Comment: Your desired output converts your *single* z to *multiple* integer values — but less than possible. Please clarify what you want and what problem you have encountered.

Comment: What is the source of `z`? Why are the `int`s nested in tuples, in lists, inside a tuple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code will pick up the first sub-list viz.

> [(468000,)]

And extract its 0th element which is a tuple

> (468000,)

Applying further indexing to it, the 0th element of the tuple will be extracted.

```
za, zb, zc = [element[0][0] for element in z]
```

Each element of the list will then be assigned to `za`, `zb`, `zc`.

This is assuming that your sub-list will contain just one tuple and that tuple will contain just one integer.